# Dealing with the "depends on non-NOTIFYable properties" warning

Tags: c++, qt, properties, notifications, qml

I have a C++ object exposed to QML with a "sort of" read-only property, except that the property still needs to be set from QML, so it has a `WRITE` method defined, but other than the initial **mandatory** setting it never changes, so I feel like a `NOTIFY` is redundant, as it will already have that value set at the time of its usage, and it will never change.

However, QML doesn't share my feeling, and regardless it spews out a "Expression depends on non-NOTIFYable properties" warning.

Due to the way objects are instantiated using a property is the only applicable way of setting that value, it is not possible to use an invokable setter as such would require the object to already be "completed" and it cannot really complete without that value. Thus the need of the property mechanism and a `WRITE` method, which unfortunately leads Qt to believe that the property will change. I tried setting the property as `CONSTANT` but that doesn't seem to stack with having a `WRITE` method.

I've put a dummy signal as a temporary measure to deal with the flood of warnings, but I'd prefer if there was a more elegant way to deal with this. Again, the very design practically eliminates the possibility of setting this value after its initial setting, but since it is a C++ object and the value needs to be set on a per-object basis, it is not applicable to use a QML `readonly property` either. Is there a work-around for this that doesn't involve the redundant signal?

---

Just to clarify, the underlying problem here is that in its current state, QML has pretty much no way to initialize a read only property of an object, implemented in C++. Such a property wouldn't have a setter (if it would then it would spew the "depends on..." warning), and there is no way to pass a value to the object's constructor. As described in my answer below, there are hacks around this, but they are either limited in application or rather inconvenient. In C++ you can do even initialization of const members on a per-instance basis by passing the value to the constructor which does the initialization in the initializer list, but not in QML. Even in pure QML, read only properties must be initialized on the spot, it is not possible to leave them uninitialized (`readonly property type name` without `: statement`) and delay that until the instantiation and get per-instance initialization (`Obj { name : initValue }`). You could do this:

```
Item { // T.qml
  readonly property int r : w
  property int w
}
...
T { w: value }
```

but it... kind of defeats the purpose... And considering that a property can be "bound" only once in the body of its instantiation, I think this could be seen as an act of initialization, while further assignment or imperative rebinding (`Qt.binding()`) is prohibited. A setter without the redundant notification signal would do the trick, however qtquick's implementation design assumes that if it has a setter it will be changing, thus will complain that it doesn't have a notify signal, which IMO is a design oversight - that is, not providing any way to initialize a read only property on the QML side on per-instance basis. And currently, as I already mentioned, the 3 possible solutions come either with overheads (have a notify signal), limitations (set value before object creation - only applicable for dynamic instantiation) or major inconveniences (use setter and getter slots without implementing the actual property interface).

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on what you need the value for.

If the property is used in any property binding then you will need the notification, otherwise you end up in a situtation where you rely on the order of object instantiations and binding evaluations.

E.g. if it is used in a binding elsewhere without having an associated notification signal, then you rely on the initial setting happending before any such binding is evaluated for the first time.

If, on the other hand, the value is only used to initialize the C++ side but never used in QML elsewhere, you could consider using a "setter" function/slot.

Comment: If the value never changes, there is no need for notification. Naturally, this mandates initial setting, the problem is that regardless of that, if it doesn't have a notify signal, Qt whines about it. It is just one of the numerous design oversights of qml I have encountered. In my case it was a unique id that persists across sessions. Once set it will never ever change... ever. Unfortunately, qtquick doesn't have the notion of "it will be set once and will never change", thus it mandates either the phony notify signal, or to implement is as a slot getter instead of a property.

Comment: Never changing and being set is a contradiction. It is either a fixed value or it can be set. The former doesn't need a notification signal as the propery can be marked as constant, the latter needs a way to notify the engine when the value changes.
Even a single change is a change

Comment: If the fixed value can't be set ever then it is entirely useless and pointless, since you will never be able to set it to any meaningful value, it would only be indefinite and indeterminate. What's different about const values is not that they can't be set, but that they can only be set once. In C++ you can set const members in the constructor initializer list. Thus I say "design oversight" as with QML you don't get to pass data to the constructor, and there is pretty much no way to initialize a read only property of a C++ object in QML.

Comment: A property can either change or not change.
One that can change, even if it changes just once, needs to be able to notify the QML engine about that change.
I don't think it would be wise to rely on order of execution in a declarative environment, e.g. to mark a property as CONSTANT and relying on setting it before any binding containing it is evaluated.
Keeping the property notifyable would be safer: whether the value is set before or after initial binding evaluation, the final values will be correct

Comment: Except that it generates unnecessary overhead. Let's try and be objective for a moment here, and to abstract from your understandable bias - the inability to initialize read only properties on the QML side is a problem and a design flaw. Honestly, I'd understand pretending it is not if it was some singular exception, but when qtquick is plagued by numerous such limitations, the refusal to acknowledge such problems doesn't really make the product appear better. Two weeks ago, I found entire 5 different bugs in qml in just a single day. That's what speaks to me about quality...

Comment: So what you are suggesting is something that looks like a property in some cases but isn't actually one.
Like the "properties" in ListElement. Have you looked into doing the same for your type?

Comment: Nah, that's JS objects, and those don't play with the Qt property/meta system. The clean solution would be to provide a dedicated way to initialize read only properties upon object instantiation, the quick solution would be to simply shut those warnings off, and instead of assuming that the presence of a setter implies it will change (after the initialization) just assume the lack of a notify signal means the user intends to not change the value after its initialization.

Comment: As for the actual "initialization" through my testing I did not encounter a case of any expression being evaluated before the initial value has been set. I don't know how random the order of evaluation is, but I assume if such properties are initialized first thing in the object body, subsequent references to them will already have the value initialized. That kind of the idea of the C++ constructor initializer list - it is implicitly executed before the constructor code, but even then you have to mind the actual order of initialization because there might be dependencies.

Comment: If you are not initializing "properties" with a fixed value like a ListElement, what are you doing then?
When a property gets written initially depends a bit on the complexity of the right hand side expression. Simple ones, like literals, seem to be evaluated before the component is fully completed, more complex ones can be evaluated later

Comment: I don't see where you are getting at - ListElement's properties are **not** fixed, you can modify them via `ListModel.set()`. The property is a unique integer id that needs to be set from QML as each context has its own persisting id manager.

Comment: ListElement properties are not actual properties, basically the just look like that.
These "properties" are fixed to a simple value, they can't be used as the target of a property binding.
So I am wondering if you are not looking for something like this, a value that is not actually a property, just looks like one syntax wise for the initialization. Their values are fixed at parsing time, which sounds a lot what you are describing as your goal

Comment: In theory it could do the trick, but it is not ideal, since I have some core C++ functionality which needs access in a rather tight loop which is destroyed by having it not being part of the C++ API.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to only have a setter and getter functions exposed to QML, but without the actual property. It is a little less elegant and more verbose (an extra `()`), but at least it deals with the warning spam in the console. It will probably end up more efficient, since aside from eliminating the redundant signal, there might be less binding expression reevaluation watchers instantiated.

There is also another way, but it only works for creating objects dynamically - it will not work if you create the objects declaratively. This approach involves calling a function before each and every object creation, that function sets a static member value, which the constructor of the object uses as an implicit parameter to initialize the read only property. Thus it becomes obvious why this can only work for objects that are created dynamically, in the other case you don't get to call the function and set the value before the constructor of the object is invoked.

There are also some stock APIs that seem to come with properties that do not have notification either. For example `FolderListModel`'s `rootFolder` property, and so it generates warnings every time it is used in a binding. The solution to remove those is to use an additional proxy property and bind the `FolderListModel` property to it.